# Pretty printing JSON to a file in Node

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js

So I have a very large JSON data which I am sending to a node server via AngularJS. This is the procedure I'm using to send data :-

```
var send_data="data="+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify($scope.records,null,4));
            $http({ 
            method : 'POST', 
            url : 'http://localhost:8888/updateDetails', 
            data : send_data, 
            responseType : "json",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
          }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                console.log(data);
          });
```

I successfully managed to send a pretty printed JSON to the Node Server via the above code. However when I write this to a file using :-

```
jsonfile.writeFile(file, JSON.parse(req['body']['data']), function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

After some testing I figured out that the error is in the JSON.parse statement. Any way to pretty print JSON to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`JSON.stringify(data[, replacer[, indent]])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
jsonfile.writeFile(file, JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(req.body.data), 0, 4), function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

You also may or may not need to parse the response body though -- I believe `responseType: "json"` in the builder will automatically parse it for you:

```
jsonfile.writeFile(file, JSON.stringify(req.body.data, 0, 4), function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

**Here's a complete working isolated example of how it works:**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var req = JSON.parse('{"body": {"data": "Some text."}}');
fs.writeFile('test.json', JSON.stringify(req.body, 0, 4), function (err) {

});
```

Assuming you're handling POST requests via an HTTP listener or framework like [express](/questions/tagged/express)? Are you using a body parser to parse the incoming JSON?

Let's try:

1. `console.log(req.body)` to make sure your server recognizes the request.
2. Is it a JSON string? Is it valid? Or is it a javascript object (i.e. already been parsed)?
3. If it's been parsed, then my second suggestion will work. If it hasn't been parsed, parse it as I did in the first example.

Comment: "\"[\\n    {\\n        \\\"id\\\": 1,\\n        \\\"next_id\\\": 101,\\n        \\\"name\\\ ..... get the idea

Comment: Where you inspect it?

Comment: [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "next_id":101,
        "name": "competitions",
        "genre": [
            { .... I need this

Comment: @remus, 3. it's parsed, but your assume is wrong, parsed response is `{data: "json string here"}` and data still need to be parsed...

Comment: The JSON is a 1000 lines long. The first solution doesn't work. I'll try the fs module

Comment: I have logged it. I'm getting the JSON alright in the server.

Comment: whoops also `req.body` not `req` in my `fs()` suggestion.

Comment: You get escaped output in your `console.log` check the file directly.

Comment: Anyway, this answer is nice, and has all for solve original issue :)

Comment: Awesome! For cleaner code, I'd recommend dot notation as well: `req.body.data`.